# I can't load my YOLOv5 model in streamlit , this is the error

Tags: python, pytorch, data-science, object-detection, yolov5

```
model = torch.hub.load('ultralytics/yolov5', 'custom', path='./best.pt', force_reload=True)
```

> Exception: cannot instantiate 'PosixPath' on your system. Cache may be out of date, try `force_reload=True` or see https://docs.ultralytics.com/yolov5/tutorials/pytorch_hub_model_loading for help.

I tried redirect the posixpath to windowspath :

```
import pathlib
temp = pathlib.PosixPath
pathlib.PosixPath = pathlib.WindowsPath
```

I tried loading from local source like this :

```
model = torch.hub.load('path/to/yolov5', 'custom', path='path/to/best.pt', source='local')  # local repo
```

Answer (score 0):

try to add
`import pathlib   temp = pathlib.PosixPath   pathlib.PosixPath = pathlib.WindowsPath`

to your detect.py file